SwiftUI document based app navbar disappears
I'm developing a document-based app using SwiftUI's DocumentGroupLaunchScene and DocumentGroup, following Apple's official tutorial: Building a Document-Based App with SwiftUI: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/building-a-document-based-app-with-swiftui
Issue:
The navigation bar vanishes when opening or creating a document for the second time after launching the app. This occurs in both my app and Apple's sample code.
Steps to Reproduce:
Launch the app
Create or open a document (navbar is visible)
Return to the document browser
Create or open another document
Observe that the navbar is now missing
Expected Behavior:
The navbar should remain visible for all documents, regardless of the order in which they're opened or created.
